# JSON to PHP error - array

Tags: php, json

I'm having problems getting data from JSON with PHP.

json string

```
{"cpresult":{"apiversion":"2","error":"Access denied","data":{"reason":"Access denied","result":"0"},"type":"text"}}
```

Same json decoded

```
    array (
  'cpresult' => 
  array (
    'apiversion' => '2',
    'error' => 'Access denied',
    'data' => 
    array (
      'reason' => 'Access denied',
      'result' => '0',
    ),
    'type' => 'text',
  ),
)
```

PHP code

```
    $get_accounts = json_decode($get_accounts);
echo $get_accounts['cpresult']['data'][0]['result'];
```

error: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: `var_dump($get_accounts);` and see how it is decoded.

Comment: Either decode as an array with `true` and use `$get_accounts['cpresult']['data']['result']` or use `$get_accounts->cpresult->data->result`.

Answer (score 1):

`json_decode` will return an object by default (as opposed to an associative array). You either need to use the result with arrow pointers or [add a second parameter to the json_decode call](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)...

```
json_decode($json)
$get_accounts->cpresult
```

or

```
json_decode($json, true)
$get_accounts['cpresult']
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, your problem is that you think about PHP objects as they were Javascript objects. In PHP you can't access object's properties via `[]` like this `$get_accounts['cpresult']`. Instead, you should access them via `->` like this `$get_accounts->cpresult`